# How to detect when android option sub-menu exit?

Tags: android, event-handling

I am trying to detect if user cancels(quits without choosing any option).I tried overwriting **onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu)**, and **onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)**(in order to detect menu & back keys) in the activity. But, non of them responses to sub menu. How can i detect when android option sub-menu exit?

Comment: I suggest that you redesign your application to not care about whether the user abandons any menu.

Comment: i have to pause/resume media according to menu state. Redesign would put me behind schedule, so i choose to do as i answered below.

Comment: "i have to pause/resume media according to menu state" -- please **only** do "pause/resume media" if they actually **change the state** by **making a menu choice**. That is how menus have worked since they were introduced a couple of decades ago.

Comment: Thank you for your quick support. My main problem is context menu completely blocking VideoView, and the application is a diagnostic tool. I know ignorance giving me courage, still a custom usage like mine isn't a good idea?

Comment: "still a custom usage like mine isn't a good idea?" -- certainly not what you are describing.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up invoking context menu from options menu. Therefore, i am able to use context menu's  default methods, to detect if menu exited. Also, a custom dialog would be fine i guess, but that might be complexier.